# Oracle 19c Incorrect results with LINGUISTIC and NLS_SORT = BINARY_CI (Doc ID 2763764.1)

Tags: oracle, search, case

In the Oracle Document (https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2763764_1.html) Oracle states the following:

```
Database SQL query delivered incorrect result:
 
SESSION SET NLS_COMP = 'LINGUISTIC' + NLS_SORT = 'BINARY_CI' > No results with nested views
 
SESSION SET NLS_COMP = 'LINGUISTIC' + NLS_SORT = 'BINARY_AI' > Correct results with nested views
```

From that it sounded like using BINARY_AI would work. However I just did a test with that and I get the exact same behaviour.

My sample table has the following rows:

```
C1
--
Some_CatsLove_Dogs_aswell_too
Some_DogsLove_Dogs_aswell_too
Dogs_LoveSome_Cats_aswell_too
```

Using either BINARY_CI or BINARY_AI with LINGUISTIC and running the following query:

**SELECT c1 FROM test1234abcd WHERE c1 LIKE '%Dogs^_%' ESCAPE '^' ORDER BY c1**

I get the following results:

```
Dogs_LoveSome_Cats_aswell_too
Some_CatsLove_Dogs_aswell_too
```

Pre Oracle 19c, this works fine and all 3 rows are returned as expected.

Anybody experience this? We need to have case insensitive searches for our users.

Comment: Not sure I'm following.  You think you've encountered a bug that is documented by Oracle Support.  If you look at the Metalink note, there is a patch for the bug.  Have you applied that patch?  Does the patch not resolve the issue?

Comment: Or it may not be *that* issue. Looking at the nls_sort ref note (30779.1) there are lots of similar issues, though only listed there up to 12c for some reason. Also this specific problem shows up [in 18.4](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f80b96e5315a25778f60482fddd30fc3) and [in 21.3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f80b96e5315a25778f60482fddd30fc3). The doc you linked to says 19.3 and later, but the bug it links to is from 18.3. So.. who knows. Have you raised a service request to ask Oracle?